# How to execute the scala object using target/...jar?

Tags: java, scala, jar

There is the scala file with 2 objects: `object Test1 {...}` and `object Test2 {...}`, each object has the main method.

I built the project using `sbt assembly`, which generated jar file in the directory target: `target/scala-2.10/testproj.jar`

Now I want to execute the object `Test1` using jar file. The execution of the object `Test1` is specified as follows:

> Usage: `Test1 <fileName>`

I tried this way:

```
java -cp "testproj.jar" \
org.pack.Test1
```

But how do I pass the name of the textfile as a parameter (I refer to `Test1 <fileName>`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to need to call it like this...

```
java -cp testproj.jar org.pack.Test1 FileThatYouWishToProcess.ext
```

Assuming that org.pack.Test1 is the fully qualified path to your main class.